# import data from salesforce to databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, salesforce, databricks, simple-salesforce

I am trying to import data from salesforce to databricks using **simple_salesforce** . It is working fine with objects having less fields but started failing if my object has more fields.

**Below is what I am trying**

```
sf = Salesforce (
    username = username,
    password = password,
    security_token = security_token,
    domain="test"
)

df = pd.DataFrame(sf.query("Here I am passing all fields they are around 1000 in select query" from "+table)['records']).dropna(axis='columns', how='all').drop(['attributes'],axis=1)
```

**Error**

```
Error Code 414. Response content: <h1>Bad Message 414</h1><pre>reason: URI Too Long</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

SOQL can handle queries up to [100K](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_soslsoql.htm) characters. Have you hit that limit?

Can you cut it into 2 queries? `SELECT Id, ExternalId__c, Afield__c, Bfield__c, ...` say till "M" and then `SELECT Id, ExternalId__c, Mfield__c, Nfield__c, ...` ?

Or split them other way, maybe more and less important ones? You could even hide certain fields from the integration user (remove the checkboxes in Profile / Permission Set) if you can think of something that doesn't have to be synchronised.